# Clojure insta/parser 1.4.5, problems with ]

Tags: parsing, clojure

I have the following grammar:

```
LIST = LBRACE LISTBODY RBRACE
LISTBODY = ATOM | ATOM COMMA LISTBODY
ATOM = NUMBER | WORD 
NUMBER = INTEGER
INTEGER = #'[-|+]{0,1}[ ]*(\\d)+'
WORD = #'[a-z]([a-zA-z0-9_])*'
LBRACE = '['
RBRACE = ']'
COMMA = ','
```

Trying to parse [a,b] fails. If I replace RBRACE=']' with RBRACE='}' I can then parse [a,b}

Is there something special about the ] that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you have as `LBRACE` and `RBRACE` are fine.

I wonder that what is happening is not what you may think is happening i.e. multiple rules are working against each other. You can often tell by the error that is in the form `[:index n]`, where `n` is how far the parsing got.

`INTEGER` is a regex that has `[` and `]` in it, with a space between. Could you take them and the space and the `*` away and see how you go? I know they should be escaped in regex, but still I would try experiments along those lines.

Comment: Thanks. You pointed in the right direction. It wasn't INTEGER but WORD. Putting in  WORD = #'\\w+' allows it to parse it properly. I would guess the regex is eating too much.

Comment: `[A-z]` is very suspicious. You clearly mean `[A-Z]`. The square-bracket characters are numerically between the upper- and lower-case letters, so `[A-z]` matches square brackets.

Comment: Yes, in retrospect, it's all obvious. The [] convention was broken, so the ] was being eaten up by the regex, and instaparse was not able to find the closing ]

Thanks for the observation.